# Typo3 DCE Images

Tags: image, typo3, fluid, tx-dce

I'll try to design my own content elements with DCE (Dynamic Content Elements).
The problem I have a problem when I try to work with images. I created a select field for images which works fine. In the fluid template I have the following code for handling the image:

```
<f:image src="{field.image}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" />
```

But if I try to insert the content element, Typo3 throws me this exeption:

```
Oops, an error occurred!

No file usage (sys_file_reference) found for given UID.

More information regarding this error might be available online.
```

I already found out, that this is pretty sure a bug in Typo3, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. With the hint form [vijay rami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4156460/vijay-rami) I found out, that you have to render images in dce like this:

```
<f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'image', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
    <f:if condition="{iterator.isFirst}">
        <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" />
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Of course you have to edit in the first line "field:'image'" to your name.

Answer (score 1):

Check This Tutorial and set it accordingly. http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dce/Tutorial/Index.html
Your problem might be solved...!!

Answer (score 1):

For the Template use this code:

```
<f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'fal', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
    <f:if condition="{iterator.isFirst}">
        <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" />
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Notice `field:'fal'` is not the variable name you set, it's part of the configuration below the variable name:

```
...
<foreign_match_fields>
    <fieldname>fal</fieldname> <!-- Name of variable! -->
</foreign_match_fields>
...
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. It's a little bit confusing, because you might think "field:" is the field name. Maybe it's intended to be, but doesn't work like this in this case.